# Compiling a Java Project using Compiler API

Tags: java, command-line, compiler-construction, java-compiler-api

I'm trying to compile a whole java project dynamically using the Compiler API. My initial thoughts of achieving this is to first know how to compile it in one-line using command line, then apply the same principle/parameters on the compiler object. Problem is, I never did, err, compiled using CLI. (Disadvantage of using an IDE? Haha)

So, am I on the right track? Moreover, can the project compilation achieved in one line execution? I'm having a hard time figuring this out because of the fact that it's a project, it contains packages galore.

Comment: Any reason you can't use a build tool like [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) or [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/)?

Comment: *"So, am I on the right track?"*  If you mean 'on right track' by doing it in the command line first, I don't see the point.  The way it is implemented in the Java compilation API is quite different in terms of finding all the required source files.  From memory it requires implementing a [`JavaFileManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaFileManager.html).

Comment: @earcam I'm actually trying to learn the actual API, and not developing a project that requires me to do so per se.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Err. The compile method has an argument of 'Iterable<String> options'. That's why I thought that successfully doing it in CLI means success in the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you either want to learn javac or Java Compiler API?

If you want [CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface) compilation look at javac ([Linux](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html) | [windows](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html)).

Alternatively for API, then programmatic use of Java's compiler API will definitely require more that one line, this will get you the compiler:

[`JavaCompiler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html)`compiler =`[`ToolProvider`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/ToolProvider.html).[`getSystemJavaCompiler()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/ToolProvider.html#getSystemJavaCompiler%28%29);

Then you'll still need to load classes, write out byte code, and possibly package as a JAR.

You should use [`StandardJavaFileManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/StandardJavaFileManager.html) as you've probably many classes to manage, there's an example in the top of the JavaCompiler javadoc, but search for [StandardJavaFileManager+JavaCompiler+example](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=lm&q=StandardJavaFileManager%20JavaCompiler%20%20example) to find clearer examples like this [blog post](http://bsriram.wordpress.com/2013/07/30/generating-and-compiling-java-classes-using-java-compiler-api/).